# Cannot SSH FROM Raspberry Pi to Xubuntu machine

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, raspbian-jessie

I've just set up Jessie on my RPi 1 Model B. It's connected via LAN cable to my network, it has an internet connection active and I can SSH to it. I'm able to ping both local machines and remote websites.

I have a Xubuntu virtual machine which is connected directly to my router and has a working OpenSSH server running (I can connect to it both inside my local network and from the internet with no problems at all).

What bothers me is that, when I try connecting to this machine from the RPi, it gives me an error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.201:2222: Name or service not known".

As I said, I can easily connect to that host from any other device. As I said, I can ping that machine from the Raspberry.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

ssh -vv output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh -vv alessandro@192.168.1.201:2222
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.201:2222: Name or service not known
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: Try connecting with `ssh -vv` and edit in the output above.

Comment: It looks like 22 was added twice. My wild guess is that you typed 22 and the command added a 22.

Comment: Added verbose info as suggested by @goldilocks. Also, 2222 is indeed the actual SSH port for that machine, had to change it from the default 22 at some point because of some conflict with a previously installed web server. It has always been 2222 since then and never had any problem with it (I have to specify it everytime, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ssh -vv alessandro@192.168.1.201:2222

This is incorrect syntax, which in latter editions of `ssh` (Debian/Raspbian tends to lag substantially behind current upstream versions) seems to have been made more clear, where the output would probably have a third debug line:

```
resolving "192.168.1.201:2222" port 22
```

Notice it's the default port 22 being used.  To specify an alternate port, use `-p`

```
ssh -p 2222 alessandro@192.168.1.201
```

Usage of `ssh` is explained in the man page, `man ssh`.  Note that some SSH tools use `-P` instead of `-p` so if you are using, e.g., `scp` or `sshfs` check those pages.

Comment: Thank you very much, I might have been so used to Windows that I totally forgot the -p statement for ports. I'm feeling so dumb right now!